# Why is my void CollisioEnter/TriggerEnter isnt detecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

So i recently completed a tutorial on how to make a third person camera view, i want to use that project to **detect any collision happening to the player** by writing this line of code below:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckCollide : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Gem") //Im making sure if the player hit the object with the tag"Gem"
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);//I want to destroy the gem after collide with the player
        }
    }
    
    void Update()
    {

    }

}
```

but sadly it didnt seem to work, **so how can I detect the collision between them?**
thankyou so much for reading this far! have a nice day kind random guy! ^^

**FYI:**

I made the player inside of a parent gameobject, and so do the Gem, image below:
[image]

Comment: is there any `Rigidbody` on any of your objects? Is one of the colliders configured to be `IsTrigger`? And how are you moving the object(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can make sure that you are getting the right collision set up.

First off, your Player or your Gem objects need the component **Rigidbody**. If you don't want the rigidbody to affect the object, set kinematic to true and/or freeze constraints.

Nextly, both of your objects (**Player and Gem**) need a collider of some sort. I recommend **Box Collider**. On **one** of the Box Colliders, check mark IsTrigger. This way one of your objects can be used as a trigger. I'd recommend making your **Gem** object a trigger.

If none of this is working, double check that you have the tags in your script correctly, and that your Gem object has the right tag set for itself.